# How to set grid combo box value in javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik, rad-controls

I have combobox in grid itemtemplate how can i set the value in javascript

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn AutoPostBackOnFilter="true"
                                    CurrentFilterFunction="Contains" DataField="FAULT" FilterControlWidth="100%"
                                    HeaderStyle-Width="80px" HeaderText="Fault" ReadOnly="true" ShowFilterIcon="false"
                                    SortExpression="FAULT" UniqueName="FAULT">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <telerik:RadComboBox ID="cmbFault" runat="server" AllowCustomText="false" HighlightTemplatedItems="true"
                                            Skin="Outlook" Visible="true" Width="70px">
                                            <Items>
                                                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="NF" Value="N" />
                                                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="VF" Value="V" />
                                                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="CF" Value="C" />
                                                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="DF" Value="D" />
                                            </Items>
                                        </telerik:RadComboBox>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                        <HeaderStyle Width="80px" />
                                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

My java script

```
function vishali(){
if (difference > 5) {alert("enter into if");
                    document.getElementById('<%=cmbFault.ClientID %>').value = 'C';
                }
                else {
                    alert("enter into else");
                    document.getElementById('<%=cmbFault.ClientID %>').value = 'S';
                }
}
```

but it is not working it is saying that cmbFault is not found in the context error please help me on this

Comment: Do you want to change selected value in each GrdidView row or in some particular row?

Comment: Well, let's play "who's wants to be a millionaire". Which one row you want to use: A. Active Row B. Selected row C. Row on which user clicked D. Your choice

Comment: a.active row. it should be changed on another control focus out

Comment: var combo = $find("<%= cmbFault.ClientID %>"); 
    combo.set_text("S"); is it correct Yuriy Rozhovetskiy.

Answer (score 0):

You can do below javascript code in order to set from javascript.

```
function setCombo() {
    var combo = $find("<%= cmbFault.ClientID %>"); 
    combo.set_text("S");
}
```

And also you can have a look http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/combobox-client-side-radcombobox.html

Comment: but it is not working for me any other solution please. The combo box in side the grid and i called the script from code behind.

Answer (score 0):

To get the control inside GridTemplateColumn do the following.
JS:

```
function setCombo() {  
        var grid = $find("<%=RadGrid1.ClientID%>");  
        var tableView = grid.get_masterTableView();  
        var items = tableView.get_dataItems();  
        for(var i = 0; i<items.length; i++){  
            var rowValues = items[i]; 
            var Textvalue=rowValues.findElement("cmbFault");//access Combobox 
         }  
    }
```